# Calling interface method in razor page throws unhandled exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor-webassembly

Unhandled exception rendering component:

> Cannot provide a value for property `_accountService` on type `Inventory_Management.Client.Pages.Authentication.Login`. There are no registered service of type `Inventory_Management.Shared.Services.AccountService`.

**AccountService.cs**

```
  public interface IAccountService
    {
        Task<IResult> Login(Identity model);
    }
    public class AccountService : IAccountService
    {
        public async Task<IResult> Login(Identity model){}
    }
```

**login.razor**

```
@inject IAccountService _accountService;
<div></div>
@code{
private async Task Submit()
    {
        var result = await _accountService.Login(userlogin); // Unhandled exception
    }
}
```

Followed the Github sample, it doesn't have any scope in the startup class. https://github.com/iammukeshm/CleanArchitecture.WebApi.

References

```
Client-> Pages-> Authentication-> Login.razor.cs
Infrastructure-> Identity-> Authentication->IAuthenticationManager
Server-> Extensions -> ServiceCollectionExtension.cs
startup.cs -> services.AddServerLocalization();
```

Comment: And how do you register `AccountService`? Also try `@inject IAccountService _accountService;`

Comment: I have already injected it in _imports.razor page

Comment: Have you tried what I ahve suggested, i.e `@inject IAccountService _accountService;` inestead of `@inject AccountService _accountService;`?

Comment: Yes. But still getting this exception. Followed the Github sample, he didn't add any scope in the startup class. https://github.com/iammukeshm/CleanArchitecture.WebApi.

Comment: Clear up the confusion and post your Startup. ConfigureServices code

Comment: I think you Registered in a Server (WebAPI) project and try to use it in WebAssembly. That won't work.

Comment: @s.vinothkumar yes "he did". See [`ServiceExtensions.AddIdentityInfrastructure`](https://github.com/iammukeshm/CleanArchitecture.WebApi/blob/4fc48da49cf8ac68b38fe682c279f508c7f2a6d8/Infrastructure.Identity/ServiceExtensions.cs#L42) and call to it in [`Startup`](https://github.com/iammukeshm/CleanArchitecture.WebApi/blob/master/WebApi/Startup.cs#L26).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `IAccountService` (in the example you are trying to follow - see [`ServiceExtensions.AddIdentityInfrastructure`](https://github.com/iammukeshm/CleanArchitecture.WebApi/blob/4fc48da49cf8ac68b38fe682c279f508c7f2a6d8/Infrastructure.Identity/ServiceExtensions.cs#L42) and call to it in the [`Startup`](https://github.com/iammukeshm/CleanArchitecture.WebApi/blob/master/WebApi/Startup.cs#L26) class) registered, for example with;

```
services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>(); // also you should register all AccountService's dependencies
```

and then resolve the interface, not the implementation:

```cs
@inject IAccountService _accountService;
<div></div>
@code{
private async Task Submit()
    {
        var result = await _accountService.Login(userlogin); // Unhandled exception
    }
}
```

Comment: System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Inventory_Management.Shared.Services.IAccountService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Inventory_Management.Shared.Services.AccountService': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate 'Inventory_Management.Shared.Services.AccountService'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Comment: @s.vinothkumar it means that `AccountService` has dependencies that also should be registered.

Comment: Adding scope in the program.cs file worked. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your concrete class in Startup class's ConfigureServices method. Try the following.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
}
```

Comment: This will not help in the OP's case, cause ATM OP is resolving concrete type, not an interface and `AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>()` will register only interface.

Comment: I have already tried it (services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();). It doesn't resolve the issue.